# VOIP SipDemo Registration Failed (ERROR)

Tags: android, sip, voip

I am making an application that has VOIP.

I have proven some examples but have been unsuccessful.

1 - try with openfire

I am working with openfire, within the configuration -> server -> telephony, I have a few mappings SIP accounts.

2 - Try with 3cx (free sip server)

I have tried to access but with android but I have no success:

This is my code (Android sip demo)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

USER = 11
DOMAIN : 192.168.56.101 / 127.0.0.1
PASSWORD = 11

---

> Always get registration failed. Any idea ?

---

```
public class WalkieTalkieActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public String sipAddress = null;

    public SipManager manager = null;
    public SipProfile me = null;
    public SipAudioCall call = null;
    public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

    private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
    private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
    private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
    private static final int HANG_UP = 4;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.walkietalkie);

        ToggleButton pushToTalkButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.pushToTalk);
        pushToTalkButton.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // Set up the intent filter.  This will be used to fire an
        // IncomingCallReceiver when someone calls the SIP address used by this
        // application.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
        this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);

        // "Push to talk" can be a serious pain when the screen keeps turning off.
        // Let's prevent that.
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        initializeManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // When we get back from the preference setting Activity, assume
        // settings have changed, and re-login with new auth info.
        initializeManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }

        closeLocalProfile();

        if (callReceiver != null) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
        }
    }

    public void initializeManager() {
        if(manager == null) {
          manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        }

        initializeLocalProfile();
    }

    /**
     * Logs you into your SIP provider, registering this device as the location to
     * send SIP calls to for your SIP address.
     */
    public void initializeLocalProfile() {
        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (me != null) {
            closeLocalProfile();
        }

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String username = prefs.getString("namePref", "");
        String domain = prefs.getString("domainPref", "");
        String password = prefs.getString("passPref", "");

        if (username.length() == 0 || domain.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
            showDialog(UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG);
            return;
        }

        try {
            SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
            builder.setPassword(password);
            me = builder.build();

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
            manager.open(me, pi, null);


            // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
            // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

            manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                    public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                        updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                    }

                    public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                        updateStatus("Ready");
                    }

                    public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                            String errorMessage) {
                        updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings. "+errorMessage);
                    }
                });
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            updateStatus("Connection Error.");
        } catch (SipException se) {
            updateStatus("Connection error.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes out your local profile, freeing associated objects into memory
     * and unregistering your device from the server.
     */
    public void closeLocalProfile() {
        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (me != null) {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make an outgoing call.
     */
    public void initiateCall() {

        updateStatus(sipAddress);

        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
                // happen via listeners.  Even making an outgoing call, don't
                // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is established.
                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    call.startAudio();
                    call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                    call.toggleMute();
                    updateStatus(call);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    updateStatus("Ready.");
                }
            };

            call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
            if (me != null) {
                try {
                    manager.close(me.getUriString());
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                            "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (call != null) {
                call.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the status box at the top of the UI with a messege of your choice.
     * @param status The String to display in the status box.
     */
    public void updateStatus(final String status) {
        // Be a good citizen.  Make sure UI changes fire on the UI thread.
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sipLabel);
                labelView.setText(status);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Updates the status box with the SIP address of the current call.
     * @param call The current, active call.
     */
    public void updateStatus(SipAudioCall call) {
        String useName = call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
        if(useName == null) {
          useName = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();
        }
        updateStatus(useName + "@" + call.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());
    }

    /**
     * Updates whether or not the user's voice is muted, depending on whether the button is pressed.
     * @param v The View where the touch event is being fired.
     * @param event The motion to act on.
     * @return boolean Returns false to indicate that the parent view should handle the touch event
     * as it normally would.
     */
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (call == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && call != null && call.isMuted()) {
            call.toggleMute();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !call.isMuted()) {
            call.toggleMute();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, CALL_ADDRESS, 0, "Call someone");
        menu.add(0, SET_AUTH_INFO, 0, "Edit your SIP Info.");
        menu.add(0, HANG_UP, 0, "End Current Call.");

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case CALL_ADDRESS:
                showDialog(CALL_ADDRESS);
                break;
            case SET_AUTH_INFO:
                updatePreferences();
                break;
            case HANG_UP:
                if(call != null) {
                    try {
                      call.endCall();
                    } catch (SipException se) {
                        Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onOptionsItemSelected",
                                "Error ending call.", se);
                    }
                    call.close();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case CALL_ADDRESS:

                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                final View textBoxView = factory.inflate(R.layout.call_address_dialog, null);
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Call Someone.")
                        .setView(textBoxView)
                        .setPositiveButton(
                                android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        EditText textField = (EditText)
                                                (textBoxView.findViewById(R.id.calladdress_edit));
                                        sipAddress = textField.getText().toString();
                                        initiateCall();

                                    }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(
                                android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        // Noop.
                                    }
                        })
                        .create();

            case UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage("Please update your SIP Account Settings.")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                updatePreferences();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(
                                android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        // Noop.
                                    }
                        })
                        .create();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updatePreferences() {
        Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                SipSettings.class);
        startActivity(settingsActivity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your status ?
Launch application in debug mode and get errorCode on SipRegistrationListener.

Comment: for me it is returning -5 i.e. registration time out. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

I’m using SipDemo and encountered the issue of Registration failed as well. I got error codes of -5(TIME_OUT) or -9 (IN_PROGRESS ) or -10(DATA_CONNECTION_LOST) during each attempted registration. I got the free SIP account from sip2sip.info, and adding this line : **builder.setOutboundProxy("proxy.sipthor.net");** resolved the problem:

```
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);            
builder.setPassword(password);

builder.setOutboundProxy("proxy.sipthor.net");

me = builder.build();
```

Tested on Samsung 6.0.1 and HTC 8.0.0.